# Basic Jquery drop down menu from scratch

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a basic drop down menu with jquery.   I have one button inside the top nav that when a user hover, a div will slide down below it.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script>

$('.rentals-link').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.region-drop-down-menu').slideDown();
});

$('.region-drop-down-menu').hover(function() {
  $('.region-drop-down-menu').slideDown();
});

$('.region-drop-down-menu').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.region-drop-down-menu').slideUp();
});


</script>
```

The problem with the code though is that I can not figure out how to make the div slide up when the mouse leaves the button area AND also have it slide up when leaving the div area.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe do

```
<div class="dropdown-menu-toggle">Toggle</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu-content">...</div>
```

and

```
var isInDropDown = false, isInToggle = false;
$('.dropdown-menu-toggle').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu-content').slideDown();
    isInToggle = true;
}).mouseleave(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(! isInDropDown) {
            $('.dropdown-menu-content').slideUp();
        }
    }, 1000);
    isInToggle = false;
});
$('.dropdown-menu-content').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu-content').slideDown();
    isInDropDown = true;
}).mouseleave(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(! isInToggle) {
            $('.dropdown-menu-content').slideUp();
        }
    }, 1000);
    isInDropDown = false;
});
```

So both elements check whether the mousepointer is inside of the other one before closing. Also this gives the user some time to move the cursor (1 second). My jsfiddle fork: http://jsfiddle.net/zkRq2/

Comment: I can not wrap both the toggle trigger and the drop down menu content in the same div.  I wish I could but it isnt an option with what I am working with.

Comment: This works but I have noticed one problem.  When a user enters the .dropdown-menu-toggle area and then enters the .dropdown-menu-content after going outside both areas, the menu starts sliding down and back up continuously.  Do you know how to fix this?  Here is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/zkRq2/1/.  Go from the link area to outside the link area then into the drop down area.  When you go in that order the drop down area slides down over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll want to place the dropdown menu within the main div, that way it is part of the main div.  Then when you have `mouseleave` on the main div, that includes the dropdown.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vjWPP/1/  This is what I meant, I added a div which I was referring to as the "main div".

Comment: I have more than one link inside the wrapper div though and I only want one link to trigger the slideDown - not all of the links.  How can I do that and still make it behave the same way?